# Tiara in the front?

Tags: payday-2

In Ukrainian job Bain often says "check the front too, it doesn't have to be in the back" referring to the Tiara. I've done the mission over a hundred times and never seen it in the front. So is Bain lying or is it just very unlikely to be found in the front?

Comment: To my knowledge the Tiara has to be in a safe.. Bain is lying because there are no safes in the front of the Jewelry store... However I am not a developer of the game so I can not say for 100% certainty its just not shown up, hence a comment.

Comment: Bain is incorrect in stating that the tiara can be in the front of the store, although as i remember he points to the 'loot' in the front of the store (some of these loot items are tiara's?). This is just speculation but that could be what Bain is implying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the Tiara is always in one of the safes in the back.  Bain is just an idiot.

Comment: Never ever been in the front

Comment: They recorded and added a voice line for bain, using it, even though it is both incorrect and irrelevant. Basically, they implemented that line before finishing the heist, and then removed the front spawn point(s) for the tiara.